# MVC 4 External link

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to display an external link on my website, but even with :

```
<a href="www.google.com">google</a>
```

I get the url prefixed with my website's url... I don't need any helpers. I've googled that and people seems to say that when you don't use a helper, just a basic `<a>` it should works, but it doesn't work on mine ^^
Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">google</a>
```